# web worker don't work when trying a simple use

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, web-worker

my 'main' code is this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (menu == 'Simulate') {
      let props = {
        nodes: nodes,
        edges: edges,
      }
      let newProps = JSON.stringify(props);

      let simulateResults = Simulate(props);
      handleSimulate(simulateResults);
      
      let url = new URL("src/components/app/backend/WorkerSimulate.ts", window.location.origin);
      let worker = new Worker(url.toString());
      worker.postMessage(newProps);
      worker.onmessage = function (event) {
        if (typeof(event.data) === 'string') {
          console.log(event.data)
        }
        else{
          handleSimulate(event.data)
        }
        console.log(event.data)
      }

      
    }
  }, [menu])
```

and my worker code is this:

```
onmessage = function (e) {

    data = e.data;
    postMessage('hola mundo');
    console.log('hola');
    // let simulateResults = Simulate();
    // self.postMessage(simulateResults);
};
```

This are just a part of the code.
As you see, the worker part it should just return a 'hola mundo' but it doesnt work.
I cant even do a breakpoint in the worker file.